# Test Results file name Format in Date and Timestamp in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

How do i generate the results CSV ,jtl files automatically with the date and time format?

Basically what i am trying to looking for generating the Test results files CSV and jtl files automatically with the date and time stamp  and pass that results file in the Graphs Generator , so that I don't need to keep modify the jmx files.If possible Graphs output folder also with the date and time stamp.

How do I achieve this?

please see the below screenshots
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

> 2017/04/05 16:07:49 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
>   2017/04/05 16:07:49 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
>   2017/04/05 16:07:49 ERROR - jmeter.engine.PreCompiler: invalid variables org.apache.jmeter.functions.InvalidVariableException: Expected } after __time function call in C:\JMETER\LR2JMeter\NGP\Results\NGP_PensionReport\PR_ViewResultsTable_${__time(YMDHS),}.csv
>       at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.FunctionParser.makeFunction(FunctionParser.java:139)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.FunctionParser.compileString(FunctionParser.java:82)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.setParameters(CompoundVariable.java:189)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.ReplaceStringWithFunctions.transformValue(ReplaceStringWithFunctions.java:46)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.ValueReplacer.replaceValues(ValueReplacer.java:170)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.ValueReplacer.replaceValues(ValueReplacer.java:80)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.engine.PreCompiler.addNode(PreCompiler.java:78)
>       at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:996)
>       at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:997)
>       at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:978)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:306)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Please advise me!

Thanks,
Rajani

Comment: Replace the file name with this function.

YOURSTRING_VIEW_TABLE${__time(mm-dd-yyyy,)}

E.g. ${__time(mm-dd-yyyy,)}.csv

Comment: Let me know if it works. I will post this as answer.

Comment: Naveen,Do I need define ? Could you please provide the screenshot please

Comment: Naveen,It's not working.I have attached the screenshots to the original post.I tried Folder format as well as resultsFile format .Some thing is missing.Please advise!

Comment: Your format is wrong. You should use below syntax as mentioned.

FolderName\NGP_LoadTest_Resuilts_ViewTable_${__time(MMDDYYYY,)}.csv

Comment: Ok Naveen,I will use this.Can I use same for to create folder?

Comment: Yes. You can use anywhere in the test plan.

Comment: One more question I would like include hhmmss too.Do {_time(MMDDYYYHHMMSS,)} correct format.Please confirm!

Comment: Here is the syntax: ${__time(MM-dd-yyyy-HH-mm-ss,)}

Comment: Thank yo so much Naveen!I will let you know the results!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140105/discussion-between-rpagadala-and-naveenkumar-namachivayam).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use below syntax to name your file. You can use this [cheat sheet](https://hellotestworld.com/2016/02/02/cheatsheet-for-jmeter-__time-function-calls/), if you want to change the format.

For more details about **functions**, please check [this link](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html).

```
${__time(MM-dd-yyyy-HH-mm-ss,)}
```

Comment: Wanted to add that if you want to use that as a prefix of the file watch out for treading directory separator as encoding symbol which will ruin the function usage syntax (`C:\some\dir\${__time(,)}-data.csv`) -- in such cases add another "\" prior to "$".